# ADL and friend functions of templated types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, friend, argument-dependent-lookup

I am attempting to use templates to automatically generate a large number of operators for me. They are very similar to the following code, which does not compile:

```
struct A
{
    int value = 1;
};

struct B
{
    int value = 2;
};  

template<typename ParamA, typename ParamB>
struct C
{
    C(int v) : value(v) {}
    
    friend C operator+(const ParamA& a, const ParamB& b)
    {
        return C(a.value + b.value);
    }
    
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    C<A, B> c = A() + B();
}
```

Error:

```
 In function 'int main()':
26:21: error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'A' and 'B')
26:13: warning: unused variable 'c' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Why can't Argument Dependent Lookup find the operator+ for A and B? I think it might be because it's neither in the global namespace, nor the same namespace as A or B, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Does anybody know if what I'm attempting to do here can work?

Comment: Can you make `operator+` a free (templated) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
// Struct definitions for A & B ...

struct C
{
    C(int v) : value(v) {}    
    int value;
};

template <typename ParamA, typename ParamB>
C operator+(const ParamA& a, const ParamB& b)
{
        return C(a.value + b.value);
}
```

I remove the friend declaration from inside the `C` struct because it was unnecessary. Alternatively, you could make the friend operator declaration inside the `A`, `B` classes, although this may not be what you wanted.

```
struct C;

struct A
{
    int value = 1;

    template <typename paramA, typename paramB>
    friend C operator+(paramA a, paramB b);
};

struct B
{
    int value = 2;
    template <typename paramA, typename paramB>
    friend C operator+(paramA a, paramB b);
};  

// Struct definition for C
...
// Define templated operator+ function
...
```

As noted by @Dani, defining `operator+` to be completely generic is not ideal. If the operator is only needed for types A & B, then the templates are not necessary. If not, then there are methods to constrain the types.

Comment: Overriding operators with a template accepting everything is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mansoor I really appreciate it. I will probably use something like you have provided. Could you give some details on why exactly my version doesn't work?